# Location of compiled JSP in Open Liberty

Tags: jsp, open-liberty

I added this config element to my server.xml -

```
<jspEngine keepGenerated ="true"/>
```

Will this generate compiled jsp to the disk somewhere?  IF so where?  My Open Liberty server started with no complaints about this config element, but I can't find the compile JSP pages anywhere.

Note, I'm trying to debug an issue with a JSP page & want to see how it compiled

Comment: did you find out the location of the compiled jsp?

Comment: No.  I ended up being able to resolve my JSP page issue with out the compiled version.

Answer (score 1):

Being that portions of the path where the java is saved depend on osgi and the app name, probably easiest to find them with a find command.  From the server directory (same place where server.xml is):   find . -name "_*.java"