# What is the correct location for the jspEngine config?

Tags: java, jsp, configuration, open-liberty

I am working on a small JSP project...and I want to add a configuration that is mentioned here : https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/config/jspEngine.html
Specifically, i want to add `keepGenerated ="true"`

2 questions:

1. Is the location of this config corect? I just placed it inside the server element (not clear to me from the link from above if the location is good)

   ```
    <server description="My Project">

        <featureManager>
            <feature>servlet-5.0</feature>
            <!-- needed to run JSP examples -->
            <feature>pages-3.0</feature>
        </featureManager>

        <jspEngine keepGenerated ="true"/>
        ....
    </server>
   ```
2. Where will the java files corresponding to the JSP files be generated? I want to see the java code that is generated...

By adding the property from question 1, I was unable to find the java files generated for the JSP file....I tried to run also a search but no use..I assume that the configuration might not be correct..

Thx!

Comment: 1. Yes, this is correct, the child elements of `<server>` generally don't need to be ordered.

2. The path here is dynamically calculated based on the runtime bundle and app name.  I would just use a `find` command to find them.  For me in a quick test of one of our sample apps with a JSP I see a location of
`target/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/74/data/temp/default_node/SMF_WebContainer/guide-maven-multimodules-ear/guide-maven-multimodules-war-1.0-SNAPSHOT/_heights.java`.  NOTE: the .java files get generated lazily so you might need to invoke the app first

Comment: Mostly duplicate of:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68966343/location-of-compiled-jsp-in-open-liberty

Comment: Looks like you can `scratchdir` param might help - "When this attribute is set, the JSPs are compiled to the specified directory instead of the server workarea directory."